# AddressOfEntryPoint is beyond the end of the file

Tags: .net, windows, executable, portable-executable, coff

I'm trying to understand what the `AddressOfEntryPoint` in the COFF header.

I have a "nothing" .NET exe:

```csharp
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

(I've compiled it as an x86 application)

The values I get for the standard fields in the COFF header are:

```
COFF - Optional Header Standard Fields
======================================

UInt16    Magic                         0x0000010B
Byte      MajorLinkerVersion            0x30
Byte      MinorLinkerVersion            0x0
UInt32    SizeOfCode                    0x0400
UInt32    SizeOfInitializedData         0x0800
UInt32    SizeOfUninitializedData       0x0000
UInt32    AddressOfEntryPoint           0x2356
UInt32    BaseOfCode                    2000
UInt32    BaseOfData                    4000
```

The `AddressOfEntryPoint` is `0x2356`.

The file isn't long enough for this value to be an offset from anywhere, so what it is it?

(Files at:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VClORkJKyGhd7o3YBPbCZEni1ad_mncl)

Comment: Subtract BaseOfCode to get a happier number.

Comment: Back in ~9x/XP era, when the OS didn't "know" about .NET, there was a CLR loader stub pointed to by the COFF header. I think it's still in there but irrelevant to how .NET code starts running on modern windows.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant.  That gives me `0x356` which seems to point to some data (maybe the strings table??).  I was expecting it to point to `_CoreExeMain` or `mscorelib` at `0x53A`.

Comment: Ought to be a tiny sliver of machine code, just a 5 byte JMP instruction to the mscoree.dll function.  First byte should be 0xE9.  Doesn't actually get used, but that's another story.

Comment: @HansPassant for me, `0x356` is in the middle of zero'd bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to calculate the offset of EntryPoint in the file, you need to subtract `BaseOfCode` but also add `PointerToRawData` from `.text` section. For this file, the last one is `0x200` and with the previous calculations it gives `0x556` which points to a nice `jmp` to `_CorExeMain`.

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm missing then!  The instruction that point to if `FF 25 00 20 40`.  Hans said above that it should start with `0xE9`.  How com this is different?

Comment: E9 is a call, this is jmp

Comment: YES!  When I disassembly that I get `jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x402000 `m which I _think_ looks about right,  Thank you!

Comment: The jump location is, `0x402000`, but `_CoreExeMain` is at `0x054A`.  How does the value `0x402000` map?

Comment: What is @ 0x54A? If you are referring to offset 0x53A then it's just a string there not the code for _CorExeMain.

Comment: Aye, where does `0x0402000` point?  I know it should point to the import table entry.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-the-clr-loader-stub/)